# None of the YouTube javascript is loading inside an html page

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

This is the YouTube code.

None of it is working inside an html page.

I'm opening it from file.
file:///C:/Users/Desktop/test.html

How come, why is it not working, and how would I get it to work?

I don't understand what the issue is. It works perfectly fine inside jsfiddle, but once I put it inside an html page, none of the javascript is working.

https://jsfiddle.net/3mxdzt4u/7/

**Html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My HTML Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container {
  width: 990px;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #000000;
}

.container-top {
  position: relative;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 0 0 45px 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/jEMIULl.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.video-contain {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 277px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.jacket {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/fzdYu8g.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.jacket-middle {
  background-position: 0 -80px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.jacket-right {
  background-position: 0 -80px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.jacket .circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: transform 0.1s ease 0s;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 0 10px;
}

.jacket .play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 38px;
  height: 22px;
  fill: #0059dd;
}

..jacket .circle:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.jacket .circle:hover .play {
  fill: red;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 277px;
  height: 207px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.wrap iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 277px;
  height: 207px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container-left {
  float: left;
  width: 606px;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-left .jacketc {
  position: relative;
  height: 344px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 45px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/gI9vM6E.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container-left .jacketc .play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  fill: #fa33fc;
}

.container-left .jacketc .lines::before,
.container-left .jacketc .lines::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 198px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0059dd;
}

.container-left .jacketc .lines::after {
  left: 399px;
}

.container-left .wrapg {
  position: relative;
  height: 344px;
  margin: 45px 0 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container-left .wrapg iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 338px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container-left .wrapg .lines::before,
.container-left .wrapg .lines::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 198px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0059dd;
}

.container-left .wrapg .lines::after {
  left: 399px;
}

.container-left .jacketd {
  position: relative;
  height: 606px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 45px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container-left .jacketd,
.container-left .wraph {
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/baApP9x.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.container-left .jacketd .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container-left .jacketd .coversvg path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

.container-left .jacketd .lines::before,
.container-left .jacketd .lines::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 198px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0059dd;
}

.container-left .jacketd .lines::after {
  left: 399px;
}

.container-left .wraph {
  position: relative;
  width: 606px;
  margin: 45px 0 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-position: 0 -600px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  margin: 0 3px 0 3px;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li:nth-of-type(n+7) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: transparent;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li svg:hover path {
  fill: #0059dd;
}

.container-left .wraph .linesa::before,
.container-left .wraph .linesa::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 198px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0059dd;
}

.container-left .wraph .linesa::after {
  left: 399px;
}

.container-left .wraph .linesb::before,
.container-left .wraph .linesb::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 198px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0059dd;
}

.container-left .wraph .linesb::after {
  top: 399px;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .alpha,
.playinga {
  margin: 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .beta,
.playingb {
  margin: 0 201px 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .gamma,
.playingc {
  margin: 0 402px 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .delta,
.playingd {
  margin: 201px 0 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .epsilon,
.playinge {
  margin: 201px 201px 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .zeta,
.playingf {
  margin: 201px 402px 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .eta,
.playingg {
  margin: 402px 0 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .theta,
.playingh {
  margin: 402px 201px 0;
}

.container-left .wraph .nav li .iota,
.playingi {
  margin: 402px 402px 0;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
```

```
<body>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="tcell">
    <audio></audio>
    <div class="container ">
      <div class="container-top">
        <div class="video-contain">
          <div class="jacket jacket-left">
            <div class="circle">
              <svg class="play" width="38" height="22" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M7.712 22.04a.732.732 0 0 1-.806.007.767.767 0 0 1-.406-.703V4.656c0-.31.135-.544.406-.703.271-.16.54-.157.806.006l14.458 8.332c.266.163.4.4.4.709 0 .31-.134.546-.4.71L7.712 22.04z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="wrap hide">
            <div class="video" data-id="jMAShwisnQI"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="video-contain">
          <div class="jacket jacket-middle">
            <div class="circle">
              <svg class="play" width="38" height="22" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M7.712 22.04a.732.732 0 0 1-.806.007.767.767 0 0 1-.406-.703V4.656c0-.31.135-.544.406-.703.271-.16.54-.157.806.006l14.458 8.332c.266.163.4.4.4.709 0 .31-.134.546-.4.71L7.712 22.04z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="wrap hide">
            <div class="video" data-id="-SiGnAi845o"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="video-contain">
          <div class="jacket jacket-right">
            <div class="circle">
              <svg class="play" width="38" height="22" viewBox="0 0 26 26">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M7.712 22.04a.732.732 0 0 1-.806.007.767.767 0 0 1-.406-.703V4.656c0-.31.135-.544.406-.703.271-.16.54-.157.806.006l14.458 8.332c.266.163.4.4.4.709 0 .31-.134.546-.4.71L7.712 22.04z" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="wrap hide">
            <div class="video" data-id="-SiGnAi845o"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-left">
        <div class="jacketc">
          <svg class="play" width="600" height="338" viewbox="-3 -0.3 30 24.655">
            <title>Play</title>
            <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
            <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
          </svg>
          <div class="lines"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapg hide">
          <div class="video" data-id="olhhsjFBpA4"></div>
          <div class="lines"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jacketd" title="OPEN">
          <svg class="coversvg" width="198" height="198" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
            <title>Open</title>
            <path d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
          </svg>
          <div class="lines"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="hide wraph">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li>
              <svg class="alpha" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
                <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
              </svg>
              <div class="hide">
                <div class="video playinga" data-id="ZPz3wzPlruA"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg class="beta" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
                <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
              </svg>
              <div class="hide">
                <div class="video playingb" data-id="VFMtNOxpV3o"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg class="gamma" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
                <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
              </svg>
              <div class="hide">
                <div class="video playingc" data-id="Zkf4EDjV1_g"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg class="delta" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
                <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
              </svg>
              <div class="hide">
                <div class="video playingd" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg class="epsilon" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
                <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
              </svg>
              <div class="hide">
                <div class="video playinge" data-id="EK3h0IADYrQ"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg class="zeta" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
                <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
              </svg>
              <div class="hide">
                <div class="video playingf" data-id="YOw9J4K02H4"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg class="eta" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
                <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
              </svg>
              <div class="hide">
                <div class="video playingg" data-id="ID856YDIb6A"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg class="theta" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
                <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
              </svg>
              <div class="hide">
                <div class="video playingh" data-id="VRtMZDJdIIU"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <svg class="iota" width="198" height="198" viewbox="8.5 -12.2 7 48.49">
                <title>Play</title>
                <path d="M16.036 11.58l-6-3.82a.5.5 0 0 0-.77.42v7.64a.498.498 0 0 0 .77.419l6-3.817c.145-.092.23-.25.23-.422s-.085-.33-.23-.42z" />
                <path d="M12 22.75C6.072 22.75 1.25 17.928 1.25 12S6.072 1.25 12 1.25 22.75 6.072 22.75 12 17.928 22.75 12 22.75zm0-20C6.9 2.75 2.75 6.9 2.75 12S6.9 21.25 12 21.25s9.25-4.15 9.25-9.25S17.1 2.75 12 2.75z" />
              </svg>
              <div class="hide">
                <div class="video playingi" data-id="qYEooPeyz5M"></div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="linesa"></div>
          <div class="linesb"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
const load = (function makeLoad() {
    "use strict";

    function _load(tag) {
        return function (url) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                const element = document.createElement(tag);
                const parent = "body";
                const attr = "src";
                element.onload = function () {
                    resolve(url);
                };
                element[attr] = url;
                document[parent].appendChild(element);
            });
        };
    }
    return {
        js: _load("script")
    };
}());


(function manageCover() {
    "use strict";

    function show(el) {
        el.classList.remove("hide");
    }

    function hide(el) {
        el.classList.add("hide");
    }

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const cover = evt.currentTarget;
        const thewrap = cover.parentNode.querySelector(".wraph");
        hide(cover);
        show(thewrap);
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(".jacketd ");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());


const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
    "use strict";
    const players = [];

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        const player = event.target;
        player.setVolume(100); // percent
    }

    let hasShuffled = false;

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        const player = event.target;
        if (!hasShuffled) {
            player.setShuffle(true);
            player.playVideoAt(0);
            hasShuffled = true;
        }
        if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                if (players[i] !== event.target) players[i].pauseVideo();
            }
        }

        const playerVars = player.b.b.playerVars;
        if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
        }
    }

    function addVideo(video, settings) {
        players.push(new YT.Player(video, Object.assign({
            videoId: video.dataset.id,
            host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
            events: {
                "onReady": onPlayerReady,
                "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
            }
        }, settings)));
    }

    function init(video, settings) {
        load.js("https://www.youtube.com/player_api").then(function () {
            YT.ready(function () {
                addVideo(video, settings);
            });
        });
    }
    return {
        init
    };
}());

function loadPlayer(opts) {
    "use strict";

    function show(el) {
        el.classList.remove("hide");
    }


    function initPlayer(wrapper) {
        const video = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
        opts.width = opts.width || 198;
        opts.height = opts.height || 198;
        opts.autoplay = 1;
        opts.controls = 1;
        opts.rel = 0;
        opts.iv_load_policy = 3;
        opts.fs = 0;
        opts.disablekb = 1;

        function paramInOpts(settings, param) {
            if (opts[param] !== undefined) {
                settings[param] = opts[param];
            }
            return settings;
        }
        const settingsParams = ["width", "height", "videoid", "host"];
        const settings = settingsParams.reduce(paramInOpts, {});
        const playerVarsParams = ["autoplay", "cc_load_policy",
            "controls", "disablekb", "end", "fs", "iv_load_policy",
            "list", "listType", "loop", "playlist", "rel", "start"
        ];
        settings.playerVars = playerVarsParams.reduce(paramInOpts, {});
        videoPlayer.init(video, settings);
    }

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        initPlayer(wrapper);
        evt.currentTarget.classList.add("hide");
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(opts.target);
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}
const playlist = "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g";

loadPlayer({
    target: ".jacket-left",
    width: 424,
    height: 238
});

loadPlayer({
    target: ".jacket-middle",
    width: 424,
    height: 238
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".jacket-right",
    width: 424,
    height: 238
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".jacketc",
    width: 600,
    height: 338,
    loop: true,
    playlist
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".alpha",
    start: 0,
    end: 280,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".beta",
    start: 0,
    end: 240,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".gamma",
    start: 0,
    end: 265,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".delta",
    start: 4,
    end: 254,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".epsilon",
    start: 0,
    end: 242,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".zeta",
    start: 0,
    end: 285,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".eta",
    start: 23,
    end: 312,
    loop: true
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".theta",
    start: 2
});
loadPlayer({
    target: ".iota"
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered using your browser's dev tools to check what, if any, errors are reported on the console or network tab? 

Comment: My first guess is that you're opening this from `file:///`, which won't work. You probably need to run a web server and open it via `http://localhost/...`

Comment: I don't understand what this means: https://i.imgur.com/RNYmfqa.png

Comment: It should work fine the way it is inside an html page.

Comment: No, opening it from `file:///` results in error messages about the browser being unable to load the videos. Properly hosting an html file and opening it directly from the hard drive is a big difference. (confirmed, btw; your document works fine on a local server)

Comment: Yes, I'm opening it from file. file:///C:/Users/Desktop/test.html / And how would I get it to work that way?

Comment: Get any kind of web server. Basic apache2 will do: https://httpd.apache.org/